# Trying to guess code from body-parser and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I'm just starting and fairly new with Node.js & Express, but I'm following this tutorial https://github.com/jw84/messenger-bot-tutorial , and I understand most of it, but, from the following code:

```
app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging
for (i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
    event = req.body.entry[0].messaging[i]
    sender = event.sender.id
    if (event.message && event.message.text) {
        text = event.message.text
        sendTextMessage(sender, "Text received, echo: " + text.substring(0, 200))
    }
}
res.sendStatus(200)
```

I don't understand what "entry" and "messaging" do or where do they come from in `req.body.entry[0].messaging`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`entry` and `messaging` are coming from the JSON in the POST request. On line 12 of the tutorial (https://github.com/jw84/messenger-bot-tutorial/blob/master/index.js#L12) you can see the author parses the incoming request body for JSON. That JSON is added onto the `body` property of the incoming request. So in short, it's specific to his example. If the incoming request looked like this:

```
{ data: ["messaging": "hi"], ["messaging": "bye"] }
```

then `entry` would instead need to be changed to `data`.

Additionally you can see this is part of the messenger specification in Facebook's docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart#receive_messages